# Java hibernate : Access foregin key

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

Processor.java

```
@Entity
public class Processor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private boolean running;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "firmware_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Firmware firmware;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    ...

    public Firmware getFirmware() {
        return firmware;
    }

    public void setFirmware(Firmware firmware) {
        this.firmware = firmware;
    }
}
```

Firmware.java

```
@Entity
public class Firmware {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String version;
    private String filename;
    //Getter & Settger
}
```

ProcessorRepository.java

```
public interface ProcessorRepository extends CrudRepository<Processor, Integer> {

}
```

ProcessorController.java

```
...
    @PutMapping(path = "/") // Map ONLY POST Requests
    public @ResponseBody
    Map<String, Object> addProcessor(@RequestBody Processor p) {
        System.out.println("Put: " + p.getId());
        processorRepository.save(p);


        // I want to access : p.firmware_id;
        // ex) p.setFirmware_id(8)
        // ex) int tmp = p.getFirmware_id();


        return Collections.singletonMap("success", true);
    }
...
```

Below code is possible in java/spring-boot/hibernate?

```
   // ex) p.setFirmware_id(8)  
   // ex) int tmp = p.getFirmware_id();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to correct your mapping in this way:

```java
@Entity
public class Processor {

   // ...

   // @NotFound ( action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE )
   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "firmware_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Firmware firmware;

   @Column(name = "firmware_id")
   private Integer firmwareId;

   // ...
}
```

and then set `firmware_id` via `firmwareId`.

Probably for this case you should use also `@NotFound` annotation (see [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-not-found) of the documentation)

Comment: I don't know what is this `, insertable = false, updatable = false`, but, This is working well, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
p.getFirmware().getId() or p.getFirmware().setId(id) whatever works
```

Comment: yes, but, i don't want use `getFirmware()`